# counting triangles in a graph or its complement

Tags: graph-theory

Given a simple graph $G$ [no loops or parallel edges] on six vertices, 
let $G^c$ denote its complement.
It is known that either $G$ or $G^c$ must contain a triangle 
$T$ in it. [An example of a Ramsey number I think.]

My question came up when I tried to find such a graph on six vertices 
which had only one $T$ in it or its complement. 
I believe if I did things right there are none of these.
This I tried to check by drawing a copy of each graph $G$ 
on six vertices which has a $T$ in it, 
and then looking at the complements to see if any had 
no $T$'s in them. I found none.

One way to pose my question for a general number $n$ of vertices 
is then as follows: Consider the set
of all graphs $G$ on $n$ vertices, 
and for each one construct $G^c.$ 
Count the number of $T$ in $G$ and
add that to the number of $T$ in $G^c.$ 
Finally find the minimal such sum for the given $n$ 
and call that say $M(n).$ So my above six vertex conjecture 
is that $M(6)=2.$

By considering a cycle graph on five vertices
we find $M(5)=0.$

So going further one could ask if anything is known 
about this minimum function $M(n)$ for larger $n$
[such as bounds, etc.] And does it have a name?

I would also like to see a simpler way to handle the six vertex case,
one not involving drawing all the graphs.

Comment: @Yikai Not quite.. looking for a *single* graph $G$ on six verties whose complement we call $G^c$ and wish to find one such that either $G$ has one triangle and $G^c$ has no triangles, or else the reverse -- $G^c$ has one triangle and $G$ has no triangles. [I believe there are no examples of this...]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose each edge of $K_n$ is colored red or blue. Let $r_i$ and $b_i$ denote the red degree and the blue degree of the vertex $v_i.$ Let $t$ denote the number of **non**-monochromatic triangles, i.e., triangles having at least one edge of each color. Let $a$ denote the number of $2$-colored angles, i.e., pairs $\{e,f\}$ where $e$ and $f$ are adjacent edges of different colors. Observe that
$$2t=a=\sum_{i=1}^nr_ib_i.\tag1$$
**Case I.** $n$ is even, say $n=2k.$

Then the sum (1) is maximized when $\{r_i,b_i\}=\{k,k-1\}$ for each $i,$ and in that case
$$t=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{2k}k(k-1)=k^2(k-1),$$
and so the number of **monochromatic** triangles is
$$M(2k)=\binom{2k}3-k^2(k-1)=\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}3.$$
**Example.** For $n=6$ the minimum number of monochromatic triangles is $2.$

**Case II.** $n=4k+1.$

The sum (1) is maximized when $r_i=b_i=2k$ for each $i,$ and in that case
$$t=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{4k+1}(2k)^2=2k^2(4k+1),$$
and so the number of monochromatic triangles is
$$M(4k+1)=\binom{4k+1}3-2k^2(4k+1)=\frac{2k(k-1)(4k+1)}3.$$
**Case III.** $n=4k+3.$

It's not possible to have $r_i=b_i=2k+1$ for all $i,$ since $2k+1$ and $n=4k+3$ are both odd. The sum (1) is maximized when $r_i$ and $b_i$ are as nearly equal as possible, e.g., when $\{r_1,b_1\}=\{2k,2k+2\}$ and $r_i=b_i=2k+1$ for all $i\ne1.$ In that case
$$t=\frac12\left[(2k)(2k+2)+\sum_{k=2}^{4k+3}(2k+1)^2\right]=2k(k+1)+(2k+1)^3=8k^3+14k^2+8k+1,$$
and so the number of monochromatic triangles is
$$M(4k+3)=\binom{4k+3}3-(8k^3+14k^2+8k+1)=\frac{8k^3+6k^2-2k}3.$$

**Construction of extremal graphs.** In cases I and II we can take $G=C_n^{\lfloor n/4\rfloor}$ for the red graph. In case III we start with $C_{4k+3}^k$ and (with vertices numbered cyclically) add the $2k+1$ edges
$v_2v_{2k+3},\ v_3v_{2k+4},\dots,\ v_{2k+2}v_{4k+3}.$

**References.** The function $M(n)$ is OEIS sequence [A014557](http://oeis.org/A014557); the general formula is
$$M(n)=\binom n3-\left\lfloor\frac n2\left\lfloor\left(\frac{n-1}2\right)^2\right\rfloor\right\rfloor;$$
the original reference is:

> A. W. Goodman, [On sets of acquaintances and strangers at any party](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2310464?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), Amer. Math. Monthly 66 (1959), 778–783.

Comment: For a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices,the Goodman article gives a sharp lower bound for $E+F,$ where $E$ is the number of triangles in $G$ and $F$ the number in $G^c.$ So this seems to answer my question for general $n.$ [+1 now, likely accept after I read the article more carefully]

Comment: How do you show that it is possible to have that kind of coloring?And why is it impossible to have $r_i=b_i=2k+1$ in the case $n=4k+3$?

Comment: @TahaAkbari I "show that it is possible to have that kind of coloring" in the paragraph "**Construction of extremal graphs**". The impossibility of a $(2k+1)$-regular graph on $4k+3$ vertices follows from the so-called [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) which says that the degree-sum of a graph is an even number, equal to twice the number of edges.

Comment: @bof coulld you explain more the part "Construction of extremal graphs" because I am a begginer in graph.

Comment: @TahaAkbari You didn't tell me what part of the construction you don't understand. Perhaps the notation $C_n^k$ is unfamiliar to you? I'm using $C_n^k$ to denote the $k^{\text{th}}$ [power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power) of the [cycle graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph) $C_n.$

Comment: @bof How do you prove it is the equality case?

Comment: @TahaAkbari How do I prove what is what?

Comment: @bof you showed the equality case in the part "Construction of extremal graphs." but you didn't say why they are the equality cases.

Comment: @TahaAkbari I don't understand what you are trying to ask. In Case II, where $n=4k+1,$ are you saying you don't understand why the number of monochromatic triangles is equal to $2k(k-1)(4k+1)/3$ when $r_i=b_i=2k$ for all $i$? I thought I explained that.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am missing something, the equality $2t=a$ comes from the fact that each non-mono triangle has two non-mono angles. But isn't this overcounting as non-mono triangles may 'share' these non-mono angles?

Comment: @Slugger No, they can't. Two triangles can't have more than one edge in common.

Comment: @bof Gotcha, thanks!